# Ambiguous overload || Чтение путём переопределения оператора

Tags: c++, наследование, множественное-наследование

Нужно прочитать и афишировать характеристики объекта наследованого класса путём переопределения обераторов ">>" и "<<". На пол пути компилятор выдает ошибку

```
main.cpp|83|error: ambiguous overload for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'jiloe_zdanie')|
```

В чём может состоять проблема?

Сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class zdanie
{
protected:
    int plosheadi, kol_etajei, kol_vhodov;
public:
    int plosh, kol_etajei2, kol_vhodov2;
    zdanie()
    {
        plosheadi=plosh;
        kol_etajei=kol_etajei2;
        kol_vhodov=kol_vhodov2;
    }

    int nr_etaj()
    {
        return kol_etajei;
    }
};



class upravlenie_zdaniem : public zdanie
{
protected:
    int kol_rabotnikov, kol_uborok;
    string administrator;

public:
    int kol_rabotnikov2, kol_uborok2;
    string administrator2;
    upravlenie_zdaniem()
    {
        kol_rabotnikov=kol_rabotnikov2;
        kol_uborok=kol_uborok2;
        administrator=administrator2;
    }
};

class jiloe_zdanie : public upravlenie_zdaniem
{
protected:
    int kol_kvartir_na_etaje, kol_kvartir;

public:
    int kol_kvartir_na_etaje2, kol_kvartir2;
    friend istream& operator >>(istream is, jiloe_zdanie &zdanie1);
    ~jiloe_zdanie();
    jiloe_zdanie()
    {
       kol_kvartir_na_etaje=kol_kvartir_na_etaje2;
       kol_kvartir=kol_kvartir2;
    }

};

 istream& operator>>(istream& is, jiloe_zdanie& zdanie1)
{
        cout << "Vvedite plosheadi zdania(m2): ";
        is >> zdanie1.plosh;
        cout << "Vvedite kol-vo etajei: ";
        is >> zdanie1.kol_etajei2;
        cout << "Vvedite kol-vo vhodom v zdanie: ";
        is >> zdanie1.kol_vhodov2;
        cout << "Vvedite kol-vo rabotnikov: ";
        is >> zdanie1.kol_rabotnikov2;
        cout << "Skoliko raz v nedeli ubiraiutsea v zdanii? ";
        is >> zdanie1.kol_uborok2;
        cout << "Vvedite imya administratora zdanii: ";
        is >> zdanie1.administrator2;
        cout << "Vvedite kol-vo kvartir na etaje: ";
        is >> zdanie1.kol_kvartir_na_etaje2;
}


int main()
{
    jiloe_zdanie zdanie1;
    cin>>zdanie1;
    system("pause");
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы объявили два разных оператора `>>`. Один объявлен как friend внутри класса

```
friend istream& operator >>(istream is, jiloe_zdanie &zdanie1);
```

другой определен снаружи

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, jiloe_zdanie& zdanie1)
```

Вот компилятор и не знает, какой из этих двух ему использовать. Очевидно, вы хотели, чтобы оба объявления объявляли один и тот же оператор, но по невнимательности сделали два разных. Разницу замечаете?

В коде хватает и других проблем...